# Cannot access nextcloud on LAN or outside the network

Tags: android, ubuntu, nextcloud

I cannot access nextcloud on my LAN network or outside. I suspect that it has something to do with substituting an old Android phone and port forwarding instead of buying a wifi adapter. I can assess it on the host pc by `localhost` or 127.0.0.1 but not by any other computer or typing the `IPv4` address of the android phone.

I am running Kubuntu 20.04,
the `snap` install of nextcloud,
no-ip.com domain with target IP address set to what I get when I search 'my ip',
a router that port forwards 443 to 1025 and 80 to 1026 to the IPv4 address of the android phone,
The phone is version android 7.0, port forwarding (with FWR app, it says I can't use anything lower than 1024) 1025 to 443 and 1026 to 80 both pointing to a 192.168.xx.xx (what I get with `hostname -I` on the Kubuntu machine)

I get no response from `sudo ncat -l 443` when i type `http://192.168.xx.xx:443` (android phone IP). Do you know what I can do to fix it? Also sorry if my question is garbage, I am new to stack overflow and nextcloud.

Comment: don't think your question will find answers here, you might find an answer on another stack exchange site, but i'm not sure which one. SO is used for development and i don't think this question fits in

Comment: Like a forum or something? Thanks anyway.

Comment: yeah i'm not sure where you could ask, maybe on a networking site perhaps or perhaps on a linux forum, just felt like leaving a comment so that you know why you're not receiving answers, typically this type of question won't receive answers here

Comment: thanks, I ended up biting the bullet and stopped being a tight arse and bought a wifi adaptor. That solved it. Did not help that 4 months later i bumped the power plug and killed the PC. Cheers though :)